# how can I create a new column based on blocks of rows divided by empty spaces?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a data set with one of the columns like:

`df <- data.frame(name = c("E11","E11","E17","","E12","E11","","E17","","E11",""))`

So it has blocks of different lengths divided by empty cells ordered by the size of those blocks. So, I wanted to create a new column (mutate) based on that. 
So, from that original data set, I wanted to create a df like that:

```js
+-------------+--------------+
|    name     |     clone    |
+----------------------------+
|     E11     |     cl_1     |
+----------------------------+
|     E11     |     cl_1     |
+----------------------------+
|     E17     |     cl_1     |
+----------------------------+
|             |              |
+----------------------------+
|     E12     |     cl_2     |
+----------------------------+
|     E11     |     cl_2     |
+----------------------------+
|             |              |
+----------------------------+
|     E17     |     cl_3     |
+----------------------------+
|             |              |
+----------------------------+
|     E11     |     cl_4     |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but it seems to work:

```
tmp <- ifelse(df$name=="",1,0)
tmp[1 ]<-  1
tmp <- cumsum(tmp)

df$clone <- ifelse(df$name=="",  "", paste0("cl_", tmp) )
df
   name clone
1   E11  cl_1
2   E11  cl_1
3   E17  cl_1
4            
5   E12  cl_2
6   E11  cl_2
7            
8   E17  cl_3
9            
10  E11  cl_4
11
```

Comment: or with dplyr    `df %>% mutate(g = paste0("cl_", cumsum(name == "") + 1), g = if_else(name == "", "", g)`